# Create an extra column on a Django queryset based on a JSON

Tags: python, json, django, django-admin, django-queryset

this is a very specific problem.

My model has a JSON called 'content', in that JSON there's a key called 'name'. My objective is to get the name into a new column to the queryset, but that seems hard to do, because the **`content__name`, can not exist in some cases, and if you simply select it using extra, it will throw an exception.**

```
queryset = queryset.extra(select={'_content_name': "SELECT content->>'name'"})
```

The final result needs to include both the ones that contain the name and those who don't, the ones that don't could be replaced by and character like '-' or be completely empty.
**The final result needs to be a queryset, not a RawQueryset.**

Things I tried and didn't quite work:

1. Using filtering before and trying to union with the difference of the original, can't union because of the queryset has different columns quantity or columns have different types. You can't union `content__name` that is a JSON into the same column as `content->>'name'` that is a string.

```
qs = queryset.filter(~Q(content__name__iexact='')).values_list('content__name')
qs2 = queryset.difference(qs).extra(select={'_item_name': "SELECT content->>'name'"}).values_list('_item_name')
queryset = qs.union(qs2)
```

In this case, it could also say that `_item_name` is not a valid column on the `values_list` even after using extra to create it.

2. Tried using F expression, didn't quite work because queryset get a little confused when comparing JSON:
   `queryset.annotate(_item_name=F('content__name'))`
3. Tried using RawSQL, but it doesn't work on the scenario I'm using (Django Admin).

Summarying, I need one of these items to it probably work:

- A way to union two querysets that have different values/values types
- A way to annotate F even the content being a JSON
- Or a way to convert RawQuerysets to a normal queryset, without losing the extra columns.

Answer (score 0):

The F object not working with JSONField has been documented [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29769), along with a workaround [someone posted in the comments](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29769#comment:6):

```
class KeyTextTransformFactory:

    def __init__(self, key_name):
        self.key_name = key_name

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return KeyTextTransform(self.key_name, *args, **kwargs)

class JSONF(F):

    def resolve_expression(self, query=None, allow_joins=True, reuse=None, summarize=False, for_save=False):
        rhs = super().resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)

        field_list = self.name.split(LOOKUP_SEP)
        for name in field_list[1:]:
            rhs = KeyTextTransformFactory(name)(rhs)
        return rhs
```

It is necessary to include Cast in rhs,

```
Sample.objects.filter(jsonfield__lookup__value=Cast(JSONF('value'), 
    IntegerField()))
```

The missing imports from the above referenced post are:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTextTransform
```

And the `LOOKUP_SEP` variable should probably be `'__'`.

That being said, I have tried it and it works for your annotation case. Also, it's possible `Cast` isn't necessary unless the type you're expecting is something other than `str`, I have used it with and without Cast on a string value within a JSONField and it seemed to work as expected. Not sure why the author decided on writing the `KeyTextTransformFactory` class seeing as you could just call `KeyTextTransform(name, rhs)` directly.